# Default printer change upon RDP re-connection to terminal server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rdp, printer

When a client makes an RDP connection to their server (Not using printer redirection), the default is set to the correct printer. However, when the client closes the connection (with the X button) and re-connects, their default printer changes to a different printer.

The printer is local to the server, not the client.

The server is running Windows Server 2012 R2.

I have attempted the solutions I have found through Google (cleaning registry keys, disabled "let windows change default printer") with no luck.

Any advice on this issue is immensely appreciated.

EDIT:
Another thing too note is that the printer is adding as default upon initial log in but is not being added to the server's control panel printer list. I am hoping that being able to find a solution to this control panel issue will solve the default printer setting issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following group policies on the session host:

Computer Configuration -> Windows Components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Desktop Session Host -> Printer Redirection

-> **Do not set default client printer to be default printer in a session**

and

-> **Do not allow client printer redirection**

Comment: The issue isn't that the default printer doesn't work when GP is applied at login, instead the issue occurs when the client would cross out of the connection (Lock the screen on the server) and when reconnected the default printer will change. The client then has to manually set the default printer.